# FSM to divider numbers in VHDL

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, state-machines

I am trying to implement an FSM which divides two numbers which are assumed to be sane (no division over zero). In my specs, the machine is clocked, and at each clock edge, it checks the current state.

In the `init` state, if a `start` signal is HIGH during an active edge, it initializes everything and jumps to computation; once it is done, it asserts a `DONE` output signal.

The netlist it generated uses a lot of multiplexers, which I assume is because of the way I described the `INIT` state using `if` statement.

What I would like instead is what you normally expect, like each clock edge it checks the `start` signal and if it is high, it latches the inputs and proceeds to computation.

I would appreciate any kind of feedback you have to offer though, about the entire design in general, not just concerning that question.

[image: Netlist Viewer from Quartus]

And here below is the VHDL code I have written:

```
library ieee;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use std.textio.all;

entity fsm_divider is                   -- divides a / b
    port(start : in  std_logic;
         clk   : in  std_logic;
         a     : in  unsigned(7 downto 0);
         b     : in  unsigned(7 downto 0);
         q     : out unsigned(7 downto 0);
         r     : out unsigned(7 downto 0);
         done  : out std_logic
        );
end entity fsm_divider;

architecture arch of fsm_divider is
    constant INIT_STATE    : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := "100";
    constant COMPUTE_STATE : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := "010";
    constant DONE_STATE    : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := "001";

    signal state     : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := "100";
    signal ready     : std_logic                    := '0';
    signal x         : unsigned(7 downto 0);
    signal y         : unsigned(7 downto 0);
    signal quotient  : unsigned(7 downto 0);
    signal remainder : unsigned(7 downto 0);

begin
    
    q    <= quotient;
    r    <= remainder;
    done <= ready;

    divider : process(clk)
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
            case state is
                when INIT_STATE =>
                    if (start = '1') then
                        -- latch the inputs
                        x         <= a;
                        y         <= b;
                        -- initialize outputs
                        quotient  <= (others => '0');
                        remainder <= (others => '0');
                        ready     <= '0';
                        state     <= COMPUTE_STATE;
                    else
                        state <= INIT_STATE;
                    end if;
                when COMPUTE_STATE =>
                    --OFL
                    if (x >= y) then
                        x        <= x - y;
                        quotient <= quotient + 1;
                    end if;

                    ---NSL
                    if (x < y) then
                        state <= DONE_STATE;
                    else
                        state <= COMPUTE_STATE;
                    end if;
                when DONE_STATE =>
                    remainder <= x;
                    ready     <= '1';
                    state     <= INIT_STATE;
                when others =>
                    state <= INIT_STATE;
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture arch;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The select inputs of most of the visible muxes are driven directly by `state[2:0]`, so they are there primarily as a consequence of how you encoded your states.

You have manually created a "one-hot" encoding for your three states, but the synthesis tool is not aware of this. It has to assume that the three-bit `state` variable can take on any of 8 different values, and the most direct way of handling this is to use 8-way muxes for everything that gets assigned inside the FSM. For example, the column of muxes in the middle handles everything that can be assigned to `y[7:0]`.

It would probably be better (I can't be sure, since you haven't said what synthesis tools you're using) to create a new abstract `type` for your state variable, and let the tools choose the most efficient coding style for the implementation technology. It usually goes something like this:

```vhdl
   type state_t is (INIT_STATE, COMPUTE_STATE, DONE_STATE);
   signal state : state_t;
```

The tools will usually have a way of selecting a particular state encoding style if you want to experiment.

Comment: _**they are there primarily as a consequence of how you encoded your states**_ thanks for confirming my hunch, I suspected as much. I am using Quartus and Intel tools by the way, I will try to _NOT_ manually create the one-hot encoding of the states. I appreciate the tip thanks

Answer (score 1):

When flipflops are used which do not have a separate enable input, you will always get multiplexers if the flipflops shall not store data at each clock edge: When they shall not store data, they load the data from its own q-output which must be multiplexed with incoming data. In order to reduce the multiplexers you could do 2 things: Do not latch y, if it is stable for sure. Assign to x the new value at each clock edge, independent from state. Using a statemachine is not neccessary, see this example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity divider is
    port (
        clk_i       : in  std_logic;
        dividend_i  : in  unsigned (7 downto 0);
        divisor_i   : in  unsigned(7 downto 0);
        res_i       : in  std_logic;
        start_i     : in  std_logic;
        quotient_o  : out unsigned(7 downto 0);
        ready_o     : out std_logic;
        remainder_o : out unsigned(7 downto 0)
    );
end entity divider;
architecture struct of divider is
    signal count     : unsigned(7 downto 0);
    signal ready     : std_logic;
    signal remainder : unsigned(7 downto 0);
begin
    process (res_i,clk_i)                              
        variable remainder_new : unsigned(7 downto 0); 
    begin                                              
        if res_i='1' then                              
            remainder <= (others => '0');              
            count <= (others => '0');                  
            ready <= '1';                              
        elsif rising_edge(clk_i) then                  
            if start_i='1' then                        
                ready     <= '0';                      
                remainder <= dividend_i;               
                count     <= (others => '0');          
            elsif ready='0' then                       
                count <= count + 1;                    
                remainder_new := remainder - divisor_i;
                remainder <= remainder_new;            
                if remainder_new<divisor_i then        
                    ready <= '1';                      
                end if;                                
            end if;                                    
        end if;                                        
    end process;                                       
    ready_o     <= ready;                              
    quotient_o  <= count;                              
    remainder_o <= remainder;                          
end architecture;
```

Comment: I understand a state machine may not be necessary, but this is an exercise on implementing state machines that is why I have went with this route. I appreciate a lot the insight about flipflops and why muxes have been used heavily here.

Comment: @Ait-Gacem Nabil Perhaps try a tool like [hdl-fsm-editor](http://www.hdl-fsm-editor.de/)